# Relative homology can be represented by a homology of quotient space? $H_*(X,Y) = H_*(X/Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, and $Y \subset X$.
Let $X/Y$ be the quotient space by the relation $x \sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $x,y \in Y$.
Then $H_*(X,Y) = H_*(X/Y)$ is true or not?
Similarly $\pi_*(X,Y) = \pi_*(X/Y)$ is true?

Comment: As far as I know some sufficient conditions are $(X,Y)$ satisfy Homotopy Extension Property or $Y$ is a neighbourhood deformation retract in $X$.

Comment: Thank you. To me, any book dose not show this explicitly, so,, I wonder if there was a conterexample of this.

Comment: This is not true for homotopy groups! It is the primary reason that homotopy is harder than homology. Freudenthal suspension theorem gives conditions on when the isomorphism holds.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments it is not true that $\pi_*(X,Y)$ and $\pi_*(X/Y)$ are isomorphic. Take $(D^n,S^{n-1})$. Then $\pi_k(D^n,S^{n-1})\cong\pi_{k-1}S^{n-1}$, since $\pi_lD^n=0$ for all $l$. On the other hand $D^n/S^{n-1}\cong S^n$. Take $n=2$. Then
$$\pi_3(D^2,S^1)\cong \pi_2S^1=0$$
whilst
$$\pi_3S^2\cong\mathbb{Z}.$$

Things are better with homology, although there are still restrictions. If the inclusion $Y\subseteq X$ is a cofibration, then the quotient map induces an isomorphism
$$H_n(X,Y)\cong H_n(X/Y,\ast)=\widetilde H_n(X/Y)$$
for all $n\geq0$. It is sufficient that $Y\subset X$ is a cofibration, although not strictly necessary. For instance let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be the comb space and $Y=\{(0,1)\}$. Then $Y\subseteq X$ is *not* a cofibration, although $H_*(X,Y)$ and $H_*(X/Y)$ vanish identically.

On the other hand, the isomorhism in question can fail horrendously. Let
$$X=\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$
and equip it with the base point $0$. Write $\Sigma X$ for the unreduced suspension of $X$ and $\widetilde\Sigma X$ for the reduced suspension of $X$ obtained as the quotient space $\widetilde\Sigma X=\Sigma X/\{0\}\times I$. Note that $\widetilde\Sigma X$ is the infamous Hawaiian Earring, aka the shrinking wedge of circles.

Then $\Sigma X$ is path connected and it is known that $\pi_1(\Sigma X)$ is free on a countable infinite set of generatators. Thus $H_1(\Sigma X)$  is free abelian on countably many generators. Since $\{0\}\times I$ is contractible, the long exact sequence for the pair $(\Sigma X,\{0\}\times I)$ gives rise to an isomorphism
$$H_1(\Sigma X)\cong H_1(\Sigma X,\{0\}\times I).$$
On the other hand, the first singular homology of the Hawaiian Earing $H_1(\widetilde\Sigma X)$ contains an [uncountable number of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610700001071).